# Split string mixed input into range of single values

Tags: string, range, abap

I have an input which allows multiple IDs.
They can be entered like this:

```
[  1000, 1001, 1050-1060, 1100  ]
```

Out of this input string I want to get all the single IDs.
I already found this to split after each `,`, so the part with 1000, 1001 already works.

```
data : itab TYPE TABLE OF string,
SPLIT l_bukrs_string AT ';' INTO TABLE itab.
```

My problem is the self-built range. Any idea how I could combine this with the case above to split 1050-1060 into single values?

I want to get **1050 | 1051 | 1052 | ... | 1060** out of it.

Appreciate every hint :) Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the front end tech used to capture this user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a real range/select-option for user (?) input instead. Then you would use that range to select every value from the database table.

If you cannot use a real range/select-option, then you could convert the string to one as shown below.

```
DATA: bukrs_string   TYPE string,
      split_bukrs    TYPE TABLE OF string,
      bukrs          TYPE bukrs,
      bukrs_between  TYPE TABLE OF bukrs,
      bukrs_range    TYPE RANGE OF bukrs,
      bukrs_rline    LIKE LINE OF bukrs_range,
      bukrs_table    TYPE TABLE OF bukrs.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <string>     TYPE string,
               <bukrs>      TYPE bukrs,
               <bukrs_from> TYPE bukrs,
               <bukrs_to>   TYPE bukrs.

bukrs_string = '1000, 1001, 1050-1060, 1100'.
CONDENSE bukrs_string NO-GAPS.
SPLIT bukrs_string AT ',' INTO TABLE split_bukrs.

LOOP AT split_bukrs ASSIGNING <string>.

  bukrs_rline-sign = 'I'.

  IF <string> CA '-'.

    SPLIT <string> AT '-' INTO TABLE bukrs_between.
    bukrs_rline-option = 'BT'.
    READ TABLE bukrs_between INDEX 1 ASSIGNING <bukrs_from>.
    bukrs_rline-low = <bukrs_from>.
    READ TABLE bukrs_between INDEX 2 ASSIGNING <bukrs_to>.
    bukrs_rline-high = <bukrs_to>.

  ELSE.

    bukrs_rline-option = 'EQ'.
    bukrs = <string>.
    bukrs_rline-low = bukrs.

  ENDIF.

  APPEND bukrs_rline TO bukrs_range.
  CLEAR bukrs_rline.

ENDLOOP.

SELECT bukrs
  FROM t001
  INTO TABLE bukrs_table
 WHERE bukrs IN bukrs_range.
```

Before you split the string, you would condense it, to remove all spaces. Then you would loop over the resulting parts and check if it contains any '-'. If that is the case, you split it again and create a BETWEEN entry in your range (consider if you may want an additional check to see if the latter number is actually higher). If there is no '-', you just create an EQUAL entry.

After you have your real range, you use it to select from the database. **This is because not every bukrs in that range has to exist.** You may only have 1000, 1050, 1055 and 1060, for example.

**Edit**: The reason there is no command, function module or class to convert a range to individual values is because what needs to be done changes heavily depending on WHAT data the range is for and if/how much values need to be verified. 
If you have an integer range, then all you need to do is take the from-value and add 1 to it until you reach the to-value. What about a range of binary floating point numbers? What about a range of colours? What about your range of company codes, where not all of them necessarily exist? That's why the conversion has to be done manually.

Comment: Excellent! This is perfect, thank you so much! A range input should not be a problem either (would the code be shorter?) but I fear it does not allow more than one range?

Comment: It depends on the type of program you're using. If it is a report with a selection-screen, then it's no problem at all. You would just use a `SELECT-OPTIONS s_bukrs FOR t001-bukrs` instead of your `PARAMETERS p_bukrs TYPE string`. In select-options you can store as many inputs as you want, single values or ranges, included or excluded. The code needed to get every single value would then only consist of the `SELECT`. But if you're using a dynpro or WebDynpro program, then you've got to jump through some hoops to include a select-option.

Comment: I will definitely check this out as well! I am just starting with ABAP therefore many options are new to me. Imho the language is absolutely not beginner-friendly and way too bloated. Thank you so much for your help! If you don't mind I will post another comment when in need of help.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you were given a string with a list of mixed values, both single and interval BUKRS values divided by dash, and this list is separated by comma+space, then

```
DATA: input   TYPE string VALUE '1000, 1001, 1050-1060, 1100, 1300-1340',
      itab    TYPE TABLE OF char10,
      r_bukrs TYPE RANGE OF bukrs.

SPLIT input AT `, ` INTO TABLE itab.

r_bukrs = VALUE #( FOR GROUPS bukrs OF <bukrs> IN itab WHERE ( table_line+4(1) NE '-' ) GROUP BY <bukrs> WITHOUT MEMBERS ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = bukrs ) ).
DATA(ranges) = VALUE ddtest_ttyp_char( FOR GROUPS bukrs OF <bukrs> IN itab WHERE ( table_line+4(1) EQ '-' ) GROUP BY <bukrs> WITHOUT MEMBERS ( bukrs ) ).

LOOP AT ranges ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<range>).
  r_bukrs = VALUE #( BASE r_bukrs FOR j = CONV i( <range>(4) ) UNTIL j = CONV i( <range>+5(4) ) + 1 ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = j ) ).
ENDLOOP.
```

The first table expression (7th line) fills `r_bukrs` with unique values from initial table string.

The second table expression (8th line) fills `ranges` table with dash ranges found in initial table string, `1050-1060` and `1300-1340` in our case.

In the loop through `ranges` table the `<range>(4)` is the left extrema of interval, and `<range>+5(4)` is the right extrema, e.g. `1300` and `1340` correspondingly for last value interval.

Comment: So after execution I would have all IDs/(BUKRS??) in the r_bukrs table and could loop through them? Thank you so much for the help, sadly I am new to abap and the code is pretty hard to understand without deep knowledge and many specific keywords such as bukrs. I appreciate!

Comment: exactly. You can put it directly into select condition `SELECT * ... WHERE bukrs IN r_bukrs.`

Comment: Wow you even improved my question - really impressed by the SO functionality and great community. Thank you! I will keep you updated about my progess in case of new questions :) Awesome!

Comment: You are welcome! I added more explanations to my solution

Comment: Yes, the code to convert the string into a range is a lot shorter if you use commands available in ABAP 7.4+. While the code I proposed will work on a 7.0 system, it is much longer.